# can't install IBM SPSS Statistics 27 on LInux MInt

Tags: java, linux, segmentation-fault, spss, linux-mint

Whenever i try to install SPSS Statistics 27 on Linux Mint, it only installs the uninstall folder and the product.tar.gz file before it gives this unhandled exception:

```
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000004 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000080
Handler1=00007FBCC8474A90 Handler2=00007FBCC343E870 InaccessibleAddress=0000000000000000
RDI=00007FBC38298D00 RSI=00007FBC380332C8 RAX=0000000000000000 RBX=00007FBC38298890
RCX=0000000000000001 RDX=0000000000000000 R8=0000000000000000 R9=0000000000000000
R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000200293 R12=00007FBC38298D00 R13=00007FBC380332C8
R14=0000000000000000 R15=00007FBC38298D30
RIP=00007FBCCA06B86C GS=0000 FS=0000 RSP=00007FBCC81B9708
EFlags=0000000000210246 CS=0033 RBP=00007FBC38298D00 ERR=0000000000000000
TRAPNO=000000000000000D OLDMASK=0000000000000000 CR2=0000000000000000
xmm0 00007fbc38298d00 (f: 942247168,000000, d: 6,938973e-310)
xmm1 00007fbc380332c8 (f: 939733696,000000, d: 6,938973e-310)
xmm2 dcbf6451b8eff168 (f: 3102732544,000000, d: -5,841108e+138)
xmm3 9fceafdec9ffbf27 (f: 3388980992,000000, d: -1,788079e-155)
xmm4 55043de014254029 (f: 337985568,000000, d: 3,541894e+101)
xmm5 50c7502bb608eb1d (f: 3054037760,000000, d: 1,382134e+81)
xmm6 14d902688e93e04c (f: 2392055808,000000, d: 3,042891e-208)
xmm7 0d97812dffdc6812 (f: 4292634624,000000, d: 3,442362e-243)
xmm8 61e77dc19b1180b4 (f: 2601615616,000000, d: 4,227402e+163)
xmm9 000000003f800000 (f: 1065353216,000000, d: 5,263544e-315)
xmm10 bfe548887dd55560 (f: 2111133056,000000, d: -6,651041e-01)
xmm11 3fe988887a0422ed (f: 2047091456,000000, d: 7,979166e-01)
xmm12 bff2495b9b4845e9 (f: 2605204992,000000, d: -1,142910e+00)
xmm13 00000000440ce000 (f: 1141694464,000000, d: 5,640720e-315)
xmm14 0000000043ba4000 (f: 1136279552,000000, d: 5,613967e-315)
xmm15 0000000043bf4000 (f: 1136607232,000000, d: 5,615586e-315)
Module=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Module_base_address=00007FBCC9FD8000 Symbol=pthread_cond_wait
Symbol_address=00007FBCCA06B830
Target=2_80_20160106_284759 (Linux 5.15.0-91-generic)
CPU=amd64 (8 logical CPUs) (0x55bca0000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
pthread_cond_wait+0x3c (0x00007FBCCA06B86C [libc.so.6+0x9386c])
(0x00007FBCC3C0733D [libj9thr28.so+0x733d])
(0x00007FBCC845DAC4 [libj9vm28.so+0x5dac4])
(0x00007FBCC16C3A20 [libj9jit28.so+0x8c3a20])
---------------------------------------
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "gpf", detail "" at 2023/12/13 15:38:48 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/tmp/install.dir.4273/core.20231213.153848.4273.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMPORT030W /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern setting "|/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t 9223372036854775808 %h" specifies that the core dump is to be piped to an external program.  Attempting to rename either core or core.4904.

JVMDUMP012E Error in System dump: The core file created by child process with pid = 4904 was not found. Expected to find core file with name "/tmp/install.dir.4273/core.4904"
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/tmp/install.dir.4273/javacore.20231213.153848.4273.0002.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /tmp/install.dir.4273/javacore.20231213.153848.4273.0002.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/tmp/install.dir.4273/Snap.20231213.153848.4273.0003.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /tmp/install.dir.4273/Snap.20231213.153848.4273.0003.trc
JVMDUMP007I JVM Requesting JIT dump using '/tmp/install.dir.4273/jitdump.20231213.153848.4273.0004.dmp'

#JITDUMP:  vmThread=00000000020CCE00 Recursive crash occurred. Aborting JIT dump.JVMDUMP010I JIT dump written to /tmp/install.dir.4273/jitdump.20231213.153848.4273.0004.dmp
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "gpf", detail "".
```

I've already reinstalled java, installed java semeru and restarted multiple times, expected that to fix it since it seems to be a java runtime error. I'm a newbie, but i know a segmentation error means there's a patch of memory that is unacessible, idk what this may be referring to or how i can make it acessible.
plz help

update: someone asked to enter a gdb code result so here it goes
i typed `gdb -q /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` and then `disas 0x93830, 0x9386d` and this was the result:

```
 Dump of assembler code from 0x93830 to 0x9386d:
   0x0000000000093830 <___pthread_cond_wait+0>: endbr64 
   0x0000000000093834 <___pthread_cond_wait+4>: push   %r15
   0x0000000000093836 <___pthread_cond_wait+6>: movq   %rdi,%xmm0
   0x000000000009383b <___pthread_cond_wait+11>:    movq   %rsi,%xmm1
   0x0000000000093840 <___pthread_cond_wait+16>:    push   %r14
   0x0000000000093842 <___pthread_cond_wait+18>:    punpcklqdq %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x0000000000093846 <___pthread_cond_wait+22>:    push   %r13
   0x0000000000093848 <___pthread_cond_wait+24>:    mov    %rsi,%r13
   0x000000000009384b <___pthread_cond_wait+27>:    push   %r12
   0x000000000009384d <___pthread_cond_wait+29>:    push   %rbp
   0x000000000009384e <___pthread_cond_wait+30>:    mov    %rdi,%rbp
   0x0000000000093851 <___pthread_cond_wait+33>:    push   %rbx
   0x0000000000093852 <___pthread_cond_wait+34>:    sub    $0xa8,%rsp
   0x0000000000093859 <___pthread_cond_wait+41>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000093862 <___pthread_cond_wait+50>:    mov    %rax,0x98(%rsp)
   0x000000000009386a <___pthread_cond_wait+58>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000009386c <___pthread_cond_wait+60>:    movaps %xmm0,0x20(%rsp)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output from the following commands: `gdb -q /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, `(gdb) disas 0x93830, 0x9386d`.

Answer (score 0):

The crash on this instruction:

```
   0x000000000009386c <___pthread_cond_wait+60>:    movaps %xmm0,0x20(%rsp)
```

Given the value of `RSP=0x7FBCC81B9708` from the crash report, it is not properly (16-byte) aligned, as required by the ABI.

This is a bug in one of the libraries listed: `libj9jit28.so`, `libj9vm28`, etc.

I couldn't find any other reports of this happening. All I can suggest is that you try a *different version* of "SPSS Statistics" (whatever that is).